# Method "Range" of object _Global" failed

Tags: vba, excel

This question has been asked, but I can't figure out an answer for my case. I know that this error occurs when the Range is somehow not specified. But, I have specified the range, or thought I did and it doesn't want to work.

The code is designed to create two new worksheets from a coded transcript and then add different formulas to count the codes in two different ways. The "LastRow" code works for the first sheet, but not for the second sheet and I can't figure out why or how to fix it.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Here is the code:

```
    Sub FullDurationCoding()
    ' Format the file to run the Duration Codes on two new worksheets.
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Name = "Transcript"
      Sheets("Transcript").Select
        Sheets("Transcript").Copy After:=Sheets("Transcript")
          ActiveSheet.Name = "TopicDuration"
      Sheets("Transcript").Select
        Sheets("Transcript").Copy After:=Sheets("TopicDuration")
          ActiveSheet.Name = "TurnDuration"

    ' Count number of lines till "@End"
       Dim LastRow As Single
       LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 ' Add TopicDuration formulas.
    ' Add Topic Duration Count formula to column C
        Sheets("TopicDuration").Select
        Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:NON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:0""},B2))),1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:UNT"",""$TOP:SLF:SPL"",""$TOP:OTH:UNT"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:SPL""},B2))),C1+0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""TOP:SLF:CON:0"",""TOP:SLF:CON:MIX"",""TOP:OTH:CON:0"",""TOP:OTH:CON:MIX"",""TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:0"",""TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:MIX"",""TOP:OTH:OVR:FLW:0"",""TOP:OTH:OVR:FLW:MIX""},B2))),C1+1,C1+0)))"
        Range("C1").Value = 1
    ' Add Topic Duration Calculation formula to column D
        Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:NON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:0""},B2))),C1,""NO"")"
        Range("D1").Value = "Calculation"
    ' Add Subtotal Calulation to Cell E1 through E15
        Range("E1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(1,D:D)"
    ' Filter Column D.
        Range("A1:E" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>NO"

' Add TurnDurationFormulas()
    ' Add Turn Duration Count formula to column C
        Sheets("TurnDuration").Select
        Range("C1").Value = 1
        Range("C2").Formula = "=IF(A1=""CHI"",0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:NON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:CON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:CON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:0""},B2))),1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:UNT"",""$TOP:SLF:SPL"",""$TOP:OTH:UNT"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:SPL""},B2))),C1+0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:CON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:CON:MIX""},B2))),C1+1,IF(A2=""com"",C1+0,IF(A1=""cod"",C1+0,IF(A1=""MOT"",C1+1,C1+0)))))))"
        Range("C3").Formula = "=IF(A2=""CHI"",0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:NON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:CON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:CON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:0""},B3))),1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:UNT"",""$TOP:SLF:SPL"",""$TOP:OTH:UNT"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:SPL""},B3))),C2+0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:CON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:CON:MIX""},B3))),C2+1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:OTH:OVR:FLW:0"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:FLW:MIX""},B3))),C1+1,IF(A3=""com"",C2+0,IF(A2=""cod"",C2+0,IF(A2=""MOT"",C2+1,C2+0))))))))"
        Range("C4").Formula = "=IF(A3=""CHI"",0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:NON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:CON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:CON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:0""},B4))),1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:UNT"",""$TOP:SLF:SPL"",""$TOP:OTH:UNT"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:SPL""},B4))),C3+0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:CON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:CON:MIX""},B4))),C3+1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:OTH:OVR:FLW:0"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:FLW:MIX""},B4))),C1+1,IF(A4=""com"",C3+0,IF(A3=""cod"",C3+0,IF(A3=""MOT"",C3+1,C3+0))))))))"
 *****  Range("C5:C" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(A4=""CHI"",0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:NON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:CON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:CON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:CON:0""},B5))),1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:UNT"",""$TOP:SLF:SPL"",""$TOP:OTH:UNT"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:SPL""},B5))),C4+0,IF(OR(""$TOP:SLF:CON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:CON:MIX""},B5))),C4+1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:OTH:OVR:FLW:0"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:FLW:MIX""},B5))),C1+1,IF(A5=""com"",C4+0,IF(A4=""cod"",C4+0,IF(A4=""MOT"",C4+1,C4+0))))))))"
    ' Add Turn Duration Calculation formula to column D
  ***   Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Formula = "=IF(C2=0,C1,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({""$TOP:SLF:NON:0"",""$TOP:SLF:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:0"",""$TOP:OTH:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:MIX"",""$TOP:OTH:OVR:NON:0""},B2))),C1,""NO"")"
        Range("D1").Value = "Calculation"
    ' Add Subtotal Calulation to Cell E1 through E15
        Range("E1").Formula = "=SUBTOTAL(1,D:D)"
    ' Filter Column D.
        Range("A1:E" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>NO"
    End Sub
```

The line with the ***** is the one that initiates the error, but the line with the *** also gets the error when I go through the debug system. I'm guessing it must have something to do with trying to define Lastrow on two different sheets, but even when I split them into separate Sub actions and put the Dim code in the second sub, it still causes the error. This code worked earlier, but I needed to change the formula a little bit and once I did, now it won't do anything. (But I know it's not the formula because I fixed this formula in the same way on the previous lines and also in the topic duration section).

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You have 19 open parentheses and 21 closed parentheses on the first error line. The second error line has 5 open and 4 closed.

Comment: Also, try to stay away from `Select` and use `With ... End With` statements.

Comment: Thank you. Looking at all my parentheses very closely fixed it as I had one section that had the wrong If statement. You guys rock. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

1. Why to declare Dim LastRow As Single instead of Long? Single may store decimal -useless-.
2. LastRow has nothing to do, the problem relies in your formula.
3. You are using an array formula

> ... .Formula = "=IF(A4=""CHI"",0,IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(***{***..

Try to change those lines for: .FormulaArray 
PS: Don't enter the characters { } yourself.

Comment: Why would the code work for the first sheet (which also has curly braces), then, as she indicated?

Comment: Hmm you are right about it. The problem relies on those formulas. I pasted formulas in excel standalone, the formulas in those lines, are missing a parenthesis somewhere, according to Excel you may want to look at this line
**C4+0,IF(OR("$TOP:SLF:CON:0","$TOP:SLF:CON:MIX"**,... after this you are typing an extra statement for a previous if @kat shanks